# How can I implement QT (quality threshold) clustering in Perl?

Tags: perl, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I am having trouble with a QT clustering implementation that I want to implement in Perl.

[image: Algorithm]

The line beginning with "identify set", the third from the end, is the part I can't figure out.

The full paper is available [here](http://ifile.it/56l4s2u).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A sub i` is a cluster. `{A sub 1, A sub 2, ..., A sub |G|}` is a cluster of clusters.

`Identify set C in {A sub 1, A sub 2, ..., A sub |G|} with maximum cardinality` means  finding the largest cluster `A sub i`.

In perl, if the cluster of clusters is:

```
my @bigun = (
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6, 7],
                [8]
            );
```

then

```
# @C = @{ $bigun[1] };

use List::Util qw/reduce/;
my @C = @{ reduce { @$a > @$b ? $a : $b } @bigun };
```

Comment: thank you!
have another question, how to find distance from A_i to j, if A_i has more that 1 elements?

thank you!

Comment: Find the center point in the cluster, then compute the euclidean distance between that point A_icenter and j, I suppose.

Edit: actually, from wikipedia:

"The distance between a point and a group of points is computed using complete linkage, i.e. as the maximum distance from the point to any member of the group (see the "Agglomerative hierarchical clustering" section about distance between clusters)."

Comment: i mean how (mathematically) to find distance between for example @{$bigun[0]} and @{$bigun[1]}, thank you.

Comment: Well, in 1D: \sqrt [(x - y) ^ 2]; in 2D: \sqrt [(x1 - y1) ^ 2 + (x2 - y2) ^ 2], etc etc.